# Adding content to a Drupal system via a php script

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have been tasked with adding 1k pages to my Drupal system. This is in order to perform searched, optimizing my system.

This is the first time I ever use Drupal and I want to run a php script to add all pages at the same time. I have a script to run to generate the words and sentences.

The problem is how can I run it to populate the database and create these pages?

Are there modules that can help me? or is the use of generate-d7-content.sh the file I need to rewrite to add my words the only way to go?

Comment: you can use the node API, and i think you need the node_save function. You create a object of type node and you put there the info.Look into node API and you'll find there alot of help.

Answer (score 0):

The [Devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel) can generate content for you, I believe you can also alter the text it's going to insert. Other than that you could also simply create nodes in a loop, a detailed example on how to do this can be found over at drupal.org: https://drupal.org/node/1388922